# Is my question not clear enough?

Tags: support, specific-question, quality-filter

I tried to post this as a question on Stack Overflow:

> in android, how to stack ScrollView and recycler view(or any other view that extends scrollview) with each other like combine them, one on the top of the other, act like all the content are within the same scroll view?
>   I have tried
>
> ```
> <Linear>  
>    <ScrollView></ScrollView>  
>    <recycler></recycler>  
> </Linear>
> ```
>
> or on inside of the other, none of them works

but got the following message, and was not allowed to submit.

> This question body does not meet our quality standards. Please make sure that it completely describes your problem - including what you have already tried - and is written using proper grammar.

Is my question not clear enough?

Comment: what... you posted that on the main site and it got closed?

Comment: @Patrice I think they tried to post it and it was blocked due to low quality, given the error they posted.

Comment: @Kendra OH, that is an automated message he got? I thought his question was put on hold or closed with that message. Didn't know there are automatic filters to block questions straight up. Maybe a bit of context in the question here would help make this clearer? Anyway, thx for the clarification :)

Comment: @Patrice It definitely could be clearer- I'm just pretty sure I've seen this error as a screen shot from the "Ask Question" page. Derek, you need to clarify your question here. Are you indeed getting that error when attempted to submit your question on the main site?

Comment: Derek, I adjusted your question so it is *about* your question, not "as if" you are asking it here instead of *why* it got closed. Feel free to roll back if you meant to do so otherwise (fair warning: then this will be closed for being off-topic to Meta).

Answer (score 18):

Your question was [automatically blocked](https://stackoverflow.com/help/quality-standards-error) [by the site's quality filter.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92074/what-can-i-do-when-getting-it-does-not-meet-our-quality-standards) Let's break your question down and try to see why it was blocked.

> in android, how to stack ScrollView and recycler view(or any other view that extends scrollview) with each other like combine them, one on the top of the other, act like all the content are within the same scroll view?

This sentence is very long and confusing. It's wordy and could probably be a lot shorter. On top of that, your capitalization and grammar in this sentence are pretty poor. The first letter of any sentence should be capitalized, as should names, such as Android. The statement "how to stack ScrollView and recycler view" is not grammatically correct, either.

If English isn't your first language, that's understandable. If you have a friend or coworker nearby who is better with English, perhaps politely ask them to check over your grammar and see if they can help with it.

Moving on to the next part:

> I have tried
>
> <Linear>
>   <ScrollView></ScrollView>
>   <recycler></recycler>
>   </Linear>
>   or on inside of the other, none of them works

You do show the code you have tried. Great! A lot of question posters don't. You also formatted it as code<sup>*</sup>, which is another problem a lot of question posters have.

You should, however, also add more details of why this code isn't working for you. What do you expect it to produce? What does it produce instead? If the best way to describe what's actually happening is a screenshot, it's okay to add that- Just make sure it's a screenshot of what's rendered rather than a screenshot of code.

On top of all of this, check your punctuation and spelling of words. Keep in mind that all of these tips may not make your question absolutely perfect, but they will greatly improve your question and give you a far better chance at getting an answer. If your question is still not completely grammatically correct, but understandable and clear, then another Stack Overflow user can edit your question for you to further help with English and grammar.

For other tips to writing a good question, see [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in the help center.

---

<sup><sup>*I had originally missed that there was indeed code formatting in the original form of this question, which was lost when cleaning up the question.</sup></sup>

Comment: To format as code, you can also hit "CTRL+K" or use the culry brace button in the editor.

Comment: Thanks, Bradley- I forgot to add that in.

Comment: (\*cough\*) okay it seems that I, in turn, missed it only needed one additional space.

Comment: @Jongware Don't worry, I had trouble getting mine to format properly inside a block quote in my original answer- Hence the code block by itself. So it takes five spaces for a code block in a block quote?

Comment: I'm still curious as to what specifically caused his question to be filtered out.  I've seen so many questions on SO that are grammatically a train wreck.  I guess the filter just isn't that great.

Comment: @CrazyPaste It was likely a combination of grammar, capitalization, punctuation, and length. But really, without knowing the algorithm (which they will likely never give us) it's hard to say for sure. I'm sure the algorithm could be improved, of course, but they're trying to avoid as many false positives as possible.